# Entity Framework -> Como buscar os maiores elementos da tabela

Tags: sql-server, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6

Tenho as seguintes tabelas na minha base:

```
Produto
Id | Nome | Preco
1  | fone | 100
2  | copo | 50
3  | pao  | 10

ProdutoStatus

IdProduto | Versao | Preco
1         | 1      | 101
1         | 2      | 110 
1         | 3      | 90
2         | 1      | 55
2         | 2      | 60
3         | 3      | 5
```

E preciso fazer um método que busca somente as versões mais atuais com seus devidos preços de cada produto

Estou usando Entity Framework Core para acessar essa base, já com o mapeamento das tabelas implementado.

```
var data = _context.Produto
           .Include(u => u.ProdutoStatus)
           .Where(x => x.id == x.ProdutoStatus.OrderByDescending(a => a.Versao).FirstOrDefault().IdProduto).ToList()
```

Esse código acima trás todos os produtos e todas as versões

alguém pode me ajudar?

**EDIT**

Vejam como estão as entidades dessas tabelas

```
public class Produto{
    
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Nome {get; set;}
    public int Preco {get; set;}    
    public virtual ICollection<ProdutoStatus> ProdutoStatus {get; set;}
}

public class ProdutoStatus{
    
    public int IdProduto {get; set;}
    public int Versao {get; set;}
    public int Preco {get; set;}    

    public virtual Produto Produto {get; set;}
}
```

**Importante Saber**

- Não tenho acesso para alterar as tabelas
- Eu usei um exemplo similar ao que eu tenho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei resolvendo usando SQL Bruto mesmo, segue Código para quem tiver o mesmo problema:

```
public IEnumerable<ProdutoStatus> List()
{
    return _context.ProdutoStatus.FromSqlRaw(@"
        SELECT IDPRODUTO,VERSAO,PRECO 
        FROM ( SELECT IDPRODUTO,VERSAO,PRECO, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY IDPRODUTO ORDER BY VERSAO DESC) AS rn
            FROM PRODUTOSTATUS) AS T
        WHERE rn = 1
    ").ToList();
}
```

Espero que ajude alguém

Answer (score 0):

Como não tenho as classes aqui não dá pra validar 100%, mas pelo nome das properties, seria algo assim, agrupando ProductStatus, e secionando com Max:

```
var data = _context.Produto
           .GroupBy(g => new 
            {
               g.ProdutoStatus.IdProduto,
               g.ProdutoStatus.Versao,
               g.ProdutoStatus.Preco
            })
           .Select(p => new ProdutoStatus
            { 
                IdProduto = g.Key, 
                Versao = g.Max(x => x.Versao),
                Preco = g.Key.Preco)
            });
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, mas nesse GroupBy, não tenho acesso as propriedades internas da Collection ProdutoStatus, fiz um edit com a definição das Entidades.

Comment: uma duvida, vc quer só a lista de `ProductStatus` ou quer `Product.ProductStatus` onde tenha só 1 item com a versão mais recente?

Comment: somente a ProductStatus com os Versao mais atual de todos os Products

Comment: `var result = _context.Produto
                .Select(p => p.ProdutoStatus.OrderByDescending(o => o.Versao).First())
                .ToList();` isso não resolve então?

Comment: Esse LINQ faz bastante sentido, contudo na busca retorna uma linha null, to tentando entender o porquê sendo que a chave estrangeira está correta. Ele faz alguma correlação entre a Tabela Produtos e a ProdutoStatus alem da chave ?